# How to convert List<Integer> to Map<Integer,String> using Java8 Streams

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have List and I want to convert to Map<Integer,String> using streams in java8.

```
Say for example : 
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

Then want to convert to Map<Integer,String> like 
Map({1,"1"},{2,"2"},{3,"3"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below stuff and should work fine(Tested).

```
    List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    Map<Integer, String> result =      
    li.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> i.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want map, there should be Key=Value pair, I assume you `[{1,"1"}, {2,"2"}, {3,"3"}]` want like this,

```
List<String> collect = li.stream()
                          .map(a -> "{"+a + ",\"" + a +"\"}")
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```